# Angular 7 change parentheses for %28 and %29 in url

Tags: javascript, angular, url, escaping

I have a problem with angular routes. In my app, I have a login session expiration time. So when the user is not active for 15 minutes - the app will ask him to login again.

At this time I am saving current active url in the store and want to redirect the user to it after login. I am doing this in effects with `this.router.navigate([backUrl])`.

The problem is that some routes with parentheses, for example this `http://localhost:4200/somedata/details/3043/edit/(modal:activity/6b9f7a3e-93c9-418f-a172-c2fa648d1be7)` is converted to `http://localhost:4200/somedata/details/3043/edit/%28modal:activity/6b9f7a3e-93c9-418f-a172-c2fa648d1be7%29`and in this page is not recognized by routes.

I tried to use `CustomUrlSerializer` to fix this problem:

```
export class CustomUrlSerializer implements UrlSerializer {
  private defaultUrlSerializer: DefaultUrlSerializer = new DefaultUrlSerializer();

  parse(url: string): UrlTree {
    // Encode parentheses
    url = url.replace(/\(/g, '%28').replace(/\)/g, '%29');
    // Use the default serializer.
    return this.defaultUrlSerializer.parse(url);
  }

  serialize(tree: UrlTree): string {
    return this.defaultUrlSerializer.serialize(tree).replace(/%28/g, '(').replace(/%29/g, ')');
  }
}
```

And added to App.module providers `{ provide: RouterStateSerializer, useClass: CustomRouterStateSerializer },`
But then i am always redirected to NotFound page for urls with parentheses if i am trying to open them in new browser window or just refresh page. But it still work for relative routes. Like from this url `http://localhost:4200/somedata/details/3043/edit` i can open my component by path `(modal:activity/6b9f7a3e-93c9-418f-a172-c2fa648d1be7)`

Comment: I just tried in a simple stackblitz, and there is no issue using () in url

Comment: Did you try `router.navigate([routeWithParentheses])`?

Comment: if you do it code, you can always convert it to () before navigation.

Comment: How exactly? When i use `router.navigate(['somedata/details/3043/edit/(modal:activity/6b9f7a3e-93c9-418f-a172-c2fa648d1be7)'])` it escapes it with %28 and %29

Comment: nope, I just tried, it worked for me :)

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-8vcthj?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts, landing page is home, but when you click `redirect` button, it goes to login page

Comment: Maybe the problem is with `router-outlet`. Because modal is renderer into outlet

Comment: that is why a stackblitz is very useful to show the problem and verify the solution.

Comment: Btw, try to tefresh page when you are at `(login)` page.

Comment: looks like an issue with angular itself. do you have to use () in url? something  like ~ to replace (/) should work

Comment: @mr__brainwash have you found the solution for this? I have a similar issue, where some email clients encode verification URLs changing parentheses to %28 and %29...